# Time Entry in a Week View UI Implementation Examples

Tags: user-interface, user-experience

I'm looking for some good/proven examples of UI designs for a time entry system that allow input in a week view. Are there good design examples that come to mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None that I can think of.  I am in the process of writing this type of application in my free time, but have not yet tried to do any research to see what else is out there.  Many tools work without a UI client, and simply cater the user from a web-app .. the tracking is done via some kind of tcp/ip or RPC call .. i'm not quite sure.

I could state the obvious and suggest you look at google calendar.  And then depending on the UI toolkit, many of them have demos that you might be able to use simply to get ideas going.  I use the wxPython toolkit and this comes with a very nice self-contained demo.  Many of them are fully working demo applications and have inspired more than a few improvements/features to my UI design.  Give it a shot at least.  If youre not using the wx framework at least it gives you an idea of whats out there.  The widgets used are native .. so you have a good chance going that route.

Hope That Helps ... ;0)